# Can I post the same question in 2 communities if it is related to both?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that would fit in 2 communities : Information Security and Cryptography.

Can I post it in both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, cross-posting the same question on multiple sites is frowned upon.  As discussed on an FAQ post at the main meta site here:
 [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/236563)

The suggestion is that you ask where you feel the question fits the best.  If you receive little or no response then you can request that a moderator migrates it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Because Crypto and Infosec are so closely related, we typically split questions along the lines of:

- Crypto: mathematics, theory, challenges etc
- Infosec: implementation, usage etc

But don't worry if you post on the "wrong" site we share a lot of the same community individuals, so it is likely to still be answered, and we can migrate if needed, as @Chenmunka said.